# python 3 decode program reading multiple digits as one number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I edited it according to the answer:

```
 def decode(code, key):
    decode = ' '
    for n in code:
        for t in key:
            if n == '2' and t == '1':
                decode = decode + 'a'
            elif n == '2' and t == '2':
                decode = decode + 'b'
            elif n == '2' and t == '3':
                decode = decode + 'c'
```

and etc etc. But now:

`keypad.decode('43556 96753!', '22333 13331!') #hello world!`

that's the input.

`hhiii giiig!eefff dfffd!kklll jlllj!kklll jlllj!nnooo mooom!22333 13331!xx333 w333w!nnooo mooom!qqrrr prrrp!kklll jlllj!eefff dfffd!22333 13331!`

and the output.

What is going on? I checked over the code to see if it had any typos but no.

Comment: I think you should use `t` and `n` in your if conditions. Otherwise, your for loops dont make much sense.

Comment: To elaborate: `if t == '2' and n == '1'` and so on.

Comment: Better if you post the problem statement, sample input and a sample output.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `t` and `n` instead of `code` and `key` in the `if` statements:

```
def decode(code, key):
    decode = ' '
    for n in key:
        for t in code:
            if t == '2' and n == '1':
                decode = decode + 'a'
            elif t == '2' and n == '2':
                decode = decode + 'b'
            elif t == '2' and n == '3':
                decode = decode + 'c'
     return decode
```

Comment: I did that, I edited the post for the new problems @User_Targaryen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't mean to be using nested loops?
How about:

```
for n, t in zip(code, key):
  if n == '2' and t == '1':
    ...
```